# i am getting a nil value somewhere in my code and i am unsure where it is and how to fix it

Tags: swift, xcode

Here is the `error` i am receiving

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

I know the error is caused by a `nil` value somewhere in the code but i cannot find it. Here is the code is anyone has any insight as to where the `nil` value is then help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

var randomNumber = 0
var challengesArray = [""]
var challengeNumber = 0
var mad : String = ""
var challenge : String = ""

func ChallengeBankSplitter()  {

    let fileURLProject = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Challenges", ofType: "txt")
    var readStringProject = ""
    do {
        readStringProject = try String(contentsOfFile: fileURLProject!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print ("Failed to read from project")
        print (error)
    }
    challengesArray =  readStringProject.components(separatedBy: ".") as Array
    var arrayLength = challengesArray.count
    randomNumber = arrayLength

}


func ChallengeSelector() {
    ChallengeBankSplitter()
    challengeNumber = Int((arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomNumber))))
    challenge = challengesArray[challengeNumber]
    print (challenge)
}

ChallengeSelector()
```

Comment: Which line is causing the crash exactly? Do you have an error message in console?

Comment: do you know how to set debug points?

Comment: The exception is not necessarily caused by *unexpected found `nil`*. Set the Exception Breakpoint to figure it out. And name functions with a starting lowercase letter according to the naming convention.

Comment: @ImBatman i commented out sections till the code ran, the error is somewhere in the do catch section

Comment: Use this line to get fileURL : `guard let fileURLProject = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Challenges", ofType: "txt") else { print("Url is empty") retrun }` and check if print statement is getting executed.

Comment: You are unsafely unwrapping an optional: `fileURLProject!`. Consider using a `guard-let`, `if-let`, default value, etc.

Comment: Another thing to note is that you no longer need to use `arc4random_uniform` in `Swift 4.2` - you can now use `Type.random(in: Range)`, for example, `Int.random(in: 1...10)`.

Comment: @George_E Force unwrapping is perfectly fine in this case. The file is required at **build** time. The code must not crash at runtime in this line. If it does it reveals a **design** mistake

Comment: Ensure that the Target membership of Challenges.txt includes the project that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

As I can you have given default value for below variable

```
var randomNumber = 0
var challengesArray = [""]
var challengeNumber = 0
var mad : String = ""
var challenge : String = ""
```

so accessing above must not an issue and if you facing nil issue. So make sure you access all other variable (check first optional or not) if optional then use `if let` or `guard` to avoid crash via accessing nil at run time.

Comment: The above variable cannot be nil. So, the issue is definitely not due to this.

Comment: That's what I am trying to say. I guess he might be reset it to nil or there some other variable accessing as nil

Comment: These variables cannot be set to nil. The types of these variables is not optional.

Comment: @PGDev Agreed, I missed that the same.